# Oracle SUM for integer values from a GROUP BY result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following result table from a GROUP BY query

```
I_Count | I_Number | I_Letter
4       | 100      | A
5       | 101      | B
1       | 102      | C
```

How can I add a subquery/derived table in Oracle so that the only result set is the sum of I_Count which is 10?

I_Count, I_Number and I_Letter fields are not aliases.

This is my Group by Query:

```
select I_Count, I_Number, I_Letter from table GROUP BY I_Count, I_Number, I_Letter
```

Update 1: Received a private feedback that the question needs clarity. Reinstating again that I need a subquery/derived table that the only result set is the sum of I_Count which is 10. (Although I have already marked Gordon Linoff's answer as the one that I need).

Comment: `HAVING SUM(I_COUNT) = 10`

Comment: Show the query that you have.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @RahulJain a single row and column with the sum (which is 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious answer is:

```
select sum(i_count)
from (<your query here>) t;
```

That is, just calculate the sum.  If you want the sum on each row, then use window functions:

```
select . . ., sum(i_count) over ()
from . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(I_Count)
FROM (select I_Count, I_Number, I_Letter from table GROUP BY I_Count, I_Number, I_Letter
) tab
```